# Replace an open bracket ( with !( Only at a specific location wrt a -> symbol

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to replace only a specific bracket with not of that bracket i.e `!(` And this bracket should be the one right before this -> sign in each line of the file. 
For instance, 
`(A & b) -> (b & c)`
I want to turn `(A` into `!(A`, put a not only with this opening bracket before -> 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I want to turn (A into !(A

```
echo "(A & b) -> (b & c)" | sed 's/\(([A-Z] & [a-z]) ->\)/!\1/'
!(A & b) -> (b & c)
```